# Оплата товаров на сайте, организация

Tags: платежи

Давно интересует вопрос, по поводу оплаты товаров на сайте.
Есть возможность попробовать продовать товар, но только для зарубежных жителей.
Европа, Америка в основном.
Всегда интересовал способ правильного построение оплаты товара, на сколько я помню это называется логистика или что то в этом роде. Но дело в том что "логистика" я думаю больше подходит для, массовых продаж, и когда товаров много, может и ошибаюсь.Сам вопрос в том, как правильно сделать оплату ? и какие способы более надежны, нужна оплата с помощью Visa MasterCard PayPal это 3 основных системы которые есть у многих. Но как правильно организовать именно оплату, какие могут быть подводные камни ? к примеру, возвращение денег, и т д, защита от фрода и т д, т.е если кто то купил не за свои деньги (так как только что читал об этом) но там в общем а не конкретно. Хочеться услышать ответы, бывалых, или тех кто уже создал что то подобное, или знает как это организовать. Спасибо.

Comment: Логистика – это больше к транспортировке товаров относится, а не к оплате. Почитайте про эквайринг (а если быть точнее – интернет-эквайринг).

Comment: А почему вы не хотите просто для начала поставить готовую систему приема платежей? В России это Яндекс.Касса или Intellectmoney и т. п, Для Европы с Америкой конкретно не знаю, но точно что-то есть.

Comment: Вот меня интересует что именно, как я понял там многие платят пай пелом, но дело в том что нужно знать подводные камни, в том плане, конкретно как работать с этой системой, возврат платежей и т д. Т.е допустим когда 2-3 клиента еще ладно, но когда 15, их отследить не легко всех будет, и т д. Вообщем просто мне нужно какой то готовый вариант что бы был, и какая ответственность будет и как это будет работать.